# Create .CSV File inserting values

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv

I´m new in c#, so that I want to do is to insert three values, `int,string,int` separated by comas, for example `10,Jesus,1234`, when it are inserted I want to export that values into .CSV file,

The method to export CSV FILE is this

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Insert a number followed by name and finally another number \n" + "* Note: Insert all values separated by comas");

        int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string value2 = Console.ReadLine();
        int value3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        string filePath = "Your path of the location" + "filename.csv";
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }
        var line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", value1, value2, value3);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, line);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
}
```

How can I do to insert values separated by comas and export .csv file?

Comment: Is the question how to join an array of arbitrary types and not just strings?

Comment: According to this it states it will create the file for you in needed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The question is how can I insert values separated by commas, and read it like separate columns and finally Export it into a .CSV File, for example, I write: 10,Jose,1000, first column be 10, second Jose, and last one be 1000 @Chris

Comment: If you want to read it as separated columns then use somthing like String.Split.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using:

```
String strText;

strText = String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", value1, value2, value3);

File.AppendAllText(filePath, strText);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the content that is already if the file, why not just append a new line to it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Insert a number followed by name and finally another number \n" + "* Note: Insert all values separated by comas");

    int value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    string value2 = Console.ReadLine();
    int value3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


    string filePath = "Your path of the location" + "filename.csv";
    File.AppendAllText(filePath, string.Join(",", value1, value2, value3) + Environment.NewLine);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

**EDIT** : update based on OP's comment

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filePath = "Your path of the location" + "filename.csv";

    Console.WriteLine("Insert a number followed by name and finally another number");
    Console.WriteLine("* Note: Insert all values separated by commas (ex: 10,Jesus,2000)");
    Console.WriteLine("* Note: Enter a blank line to exit");

    while(true) // Ad infinitum
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        // on blank line, confirm before exiting the application
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to exit the application? (y/n)");
            if (Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant() == "Y")
                break;

            continue;
        }

        // input validation : number, anything, number
        var values = input.Split(',');
        if (values.Length != 3 || !Regex.IsMatch(values[0], @"\d+") || !Regex.IsMatch(values[2], @"\d+"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            continue;
        }

        // save save to the file
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, string.Join(",", values) + Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("The values has been inserted into the csv.");

    } // rince and repeat
}
```

Comment: The problem is I want to insert only one line per register for example  `10,Jesus,2000`, How can I do that if program expecting int,string,int in diferent lines?

Comment: So you want to enter `"number, text, number"` in one line, and have the application accept multiple inputs like that one?

Comment: Yes, and after it export it to .csv file

Comment: Nice!, but there are another form to do that without `split` method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to enter one line separated by commas then you must only call `Console.ReadLine()` once. Then you can use [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to get them into variables.

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
var values = input.Split(',');
var value1 = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
var value2 = values[1];
var value3 = Convert.ToInt32(values[2]);
```

Then you turn the 3 values back into a single line using [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), or if you're using C# 6 then [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx).

For example, using String.Format your code would be:

```
var line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", value1, value2, value3);
```

Or, for C# 6 and string interpolation:

```
var line = $"{value1},{value2},{value3}";
```

Then, you can write this line out to the file:

```
File.AppendAllText(filePath, line);
```

However, I have no idea why you'd want to accept a comma separated set of values, split them into constituent parts and then re-combine them. Why not just write the line the user enters out to the file?

Comment: I do it like you say, and I edit code of my question, the problem is that I can't insert values like `10,Jose,1000`, because obviously program want to learn an int first, how can I do to read these values in one string and separate it ( I have a restriction that I can't use split function)

Comment: Oh, so you want the user to enter the values like `10,Jose,1000` and have the program split them out? In that case, you'll need to use [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) and only call `Console.ReadLine()` once.

Comment: Exactly I want to do that!, but one restriction of program is that I can't use Split function, how can I do without it?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the Split method? You'll have to search for the commas using [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and then use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) to pull apart the string. But that sounds like a waste of time. Just use Split ;-)

Comment: Because that's idea of csv Files (comma separated values), my administrator want´s to do it without split, he want´s to create program using only loops, variables etc. no methods. I don´t know why and I´m very angry and desesperate! Can you help me please?

Comment: Just write the user entered comma separated values out to file. They are already a CSV, why split them and re-combine them? Computer programs use methods, there's no way around that. You'll have to use methods, you already are using methods, String.Format is a method, File.AppendAllText is a method, Console.ReadLine is a method.

Comment: As you say, I need write the line the user enters out to the file, but in different columns, how can I do that without split?